# Direct x 12 image flickering on Intel graphic hard

Tags: directx-12, direct3d12

I have a weird issue only happening on my Intel HD Graphics 530

When rendering an image, some pixels color randomly change.
See the following image:
[Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVXjl.jpg)

For the problematic pixels, the graphics debugger show that the color outputted from the graphics pipeline is the correct one. But the pixel displayed color is wrong.
See: [Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di3HY.png)

From my investigations i have found that these pixels seems using information from the materials of the others. My materials information is handled by a descriptor heap. So the switch between graphics root descriptor table in my rendering loop seems to be my problem (when i only draw one object everything is fine)

Here the code snippet i use:

```
void ForwardLighningEffect::pushCommands(ForwardLigthningPushArgs data, ID3D12GraphicsCommandList* commandList, int frameIndex) {

// set PSO
commandList->SetPipelineState(m_mainPipelineStateObject);

// set root signature
commandList->SetGraphicsRootSignature(m_rootSignature);

// set constant buffer view
commandList->SetGraphicsRootConstantBufferView(0, m_constantBufferUploadHeaps[frameIndex]->GetGPUVirtualAddress());

const auto& meshes = data.model->getMeshes();
for (auto mesh : meshes)
{
    if (auto materialHandle = mesh->material.lock()) // get material handle from weak ptr.
    {
        ID3D12DescriptorHeap * matDescriptorHeap = materialHandle->material.descriptorHeap;

        // set the material descriptor heap
        ID3D12DescriptorHeap* descriptorHeaps[] = { matDescriptorHeap };
        commandList->SetDescriptorHeaps(_countof(descriptorHeaps), descriptorHeaps);

        // HERE ! set the descriptor table to the descriptor heap (parameter 1, as constant buffer root descriptor is parameter index 0)
        commandList->SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable(1, matDescriptorHeap->GetGPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart());
    }

    commandList->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &mesh->vertexBuffer.bufferView);
    commandList->IASetIndexBuffer(&mesh->indexBuffer.bufferView);

    for (auto camera : data.cameras)
    {
        updateConstantBuffer(camera, frameIndex);

        // Draw mesh.
        commandList->DrawIndexedInstanced(mesh->nbIndices, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

}

Whats wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Updating textures state when not used fixed it.

So when binding a texture:

```
commandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(/*textureResource*/, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COMMON, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PIXEL_SHADER_RESOURCE));
```

After use then reset state:

```
commandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(/*textureResource*/, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PIXEL_SHADER_RESOURCE, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COMMON));
```

Comment: You should not use COMMON if you can avoid it (though I think you might be saying this is a bug/driver fix).  Do you ever write to the texture after start of day?

Comment: Thank you for the warning. I don't write to the textures, i only bind them as pixel shader resources.